# react native TextInput border when press

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styles, border, native

i need to create border green on TextInput when it get selected/pressed
it mean
the TextInput should be with black border / none border for default
and when its pressed (the input) it will set border with green color
the issuse is : i create state and change it by "onFocus" when the input will press it will change to green
but i have a 4  inputs and when i press on each of them it will set the border to green but i want only one of them each time will set the border
so i add "onBlur" that will disable the border
and its look like the wrong way (its worked but still look like the wrong way)
please show me the right way

```
import { StyleSheet, TextInput } from "react-native";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Input = ({ placeholder, keyPad, onChangeText, stylesProps }) => {
  const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState(null);
  const focusHandler = () => {
    setIsFocus("green");
  };
  const blurHandler = () => {
    setIsFocus(null);
  };
  return (
    <TextInput
      style={[{ borderWidth: isFocus ? 2 : 0, borderColor: isFocus }, stylesProps ? stylesProps : styles.sign_up_inp]}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      onFocus={focusHandler}
      onBlur={blurHandler}
      keyboardType={keyPad}
      onChangeText={onChangeText}
    />
  );
};

export default Input;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple versions of the same component being rendered, it may be helpful to use a [FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist), which has a `renderItem` prop that can help you sort this out.

Here's the render item, where you can see the `selected` property add the style:

```
const renderItem = ({item}) => {
const selected =
  buttonArray.includes(item.label);
return (
  <Button
    onPress={() => handleSelection(item.label)}
    buttonText={item.label}
    containerStyle={selected ? {backgroundColor: 'blue'} : {}}
  />
)};
```

Here's the FlatList implementation using renderItem:

```
  const renderButtons = () => {
return (
  <FlatList
    data={areasArray}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  />
)};
```

Comment: Hey i didnt understand how it will help me to use flatLists? I need that  every TextInput will get a green border if it been choosed (the sefault should be none) and i need yo use a multiple TextInput and use them as radio button which means that only one input can be with green border each time

Comment: @Lior98 - hi  there, thanks for your note. If you add an id/label every time a `TextInput` is pressed into a local state array, the `selected` property will allow you to toggle that styling. So when a `TextInput` is pressed, add an id/name to a local array, then the `selected` property (or whatever you want to call it) can help you show the style. Note that you'll have to remove that TextInput from the array if it gets pressed twice.

Is that helpful?